# Python - can someone explain this code please?

Tags: python

```
def divisible_by(numbers, divisor):
    return [x for x in numbers if x % divisor == 0]
```

i know it returns the divisible numbers from the array of numbers, but can someone explain how it gets there?

I am learning python as my first language, but i have not got to arrays yet.

i am mostly confused by this part "x for x in numbers if x"

Thanks

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python list comprehension", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  All the downvotes are related to you not understanding the reason for Stack Overflow.  Please read this -- How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and repost your question or move it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “list comprehension” mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called "list comprehension". In one line, it creates a new list of all the numbers in "numbers" that are divisible by divisor. That's what the modulo (%) is checking. It checks that the remainder of the division is equal to 0.

The list comprehension is equivalent to saying:

```
divisible_numbers = []
for x in numbers:
    if x % divisor == 0:
        divisible_numbers.append(x)
return divisible_numbers
```